# Как подготовить проект Unity для git?

Tags: unity3d, git, unity3d-faq

Какие обязательные шаги нужно предпринять, чтобы подготовить Unity-проект для отправки в репозиторий (git), например, на GitHub? Не хочется хранить ненужные файлы (особенно временные); также хотелось бы отправлять как можно меньше бинарных файлов.

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How to prepare a Unity project for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/)» [@German](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267265/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573405/

Answer (score 10):

Откройте свой проект в редакторе Unity и выполните следующие шаги:

1. Выберите параметр **External option** в **Unity** → **Preferences** → **Packages** → **Repository** (только для версий Unity < 4.5)
2. Используйте **Visible Meta Files** в  **Edit** → **Project Settings** → **Editor** → **Version Control Mode**
3. Используйте **Force Text** в **Edit** → **Project Settings** → **Editor** → **Asset Serialization Mode**
4. Сохраните сцену и проект из меню **File**.
5. Выйдите из Unity; вы можете удалить директории **Library** и **Temp** в директории проекта — можно удалять все, кроме директорий **Assets** и **ProjectSettings**.

Если вы уже создали новый пустой удаленный git-репозиторий (например, на GitHub), настало время отправить ваш код. Откройте командную строку и выполните следующие действия:

```
cd to/your/unity/project/folder
git init
git add *  
git commit -m "First commit"  
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git   
git push -u origin master
```

Теперь, удерживая Option или левую клавишу Alt, откройте свой Unity-проект. Это заставит Unity восстановить директорию Library (этот шаг может не понадобиться: я видел, как Unity восстанавливает директорию Library даже если вы не удерживали никакой клавиши).

Наконец, сделайте так, чтобы git игнорировал директории Library и Temp, то есть чтобы они не загрузались на сервер (добавьте их в файл *.gitignore*). Помните, что вы отправляете на удаленный сервер только директории *Assets* и *ProjectSettings*.

А вот мой личный «рецепт» *.gitignore* для Unity-проектов (я работаю на Macbook):

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Obj/
UnityGenerated/
Library/
Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
ExportedObj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

<sub>Перевод ответа «[How to prepare a Unity project for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573406/564240)» [@German](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267265/).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

- Я использую следующий алгоритм

  1. Репозиторий создан на Bitbucket
  2. Посредником между проектом Unity и Bitbucket выступает бесплатная программа Sourcetree
  3. Файл .gitignore выглядит следующим образом:

Library/
    Temp/
    Obj/
    Build/
    Builds/
    Assets/AssetStore*

```
# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedOBj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityprof
*.sin
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage
```

Проект весом в 1,5 ГБ загрузился успешно,все работает корректно

[Источник](https://youtu.be/f5tUSQ0apxg)