# Unity3d "Ctrl + B" удалил объекты и сцену

Tags: unity3d

Случайно нажал "Ctrl + B" в Unity, меня перекинуло на другую сцену, и при этом когда вернулся в старую сцену последние 2 часа работы исчезли, при том, что я периодически сохранял проект. Можно ли всё как-то вернуть?

Comment: видимо не сохранял. На какую сцену перекинуло? Ctrl + B - собирает и запускает проект.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Во время сборки перекинуло на несуществующую пустую сцену, а после того, как сборка завершилась, сцена вернулась обратно в состояние, которое было 2 часа назад. Дело в том, что где-то минут за 20 до того как это произошло, я собрал и запустил проект, так что вариант "не сохранил" отпадает.

Comment: Не сохраняя сцену нажал Ctrl + B у себя - все осталось на месте. Возможно проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Не знаю можно ли решить проблему, но советую отныне делать следующее: **1)** научиться пользоваться ГИТом (Git) **2)** создать репо у себя в папке с проектом и отныне все будет сохраняться в любом случае........каждый чих  и каждый вздох............. советую почитать [Как подготовить проект Unity для git?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519563/191482)